# ASP's Request.IsLocal always true in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I'm trying to detect if the website is running in local to display the stack trace instead of a nice server error page. I've been happily using `Request.IsLocal` in the `Global.asax.cs` file locally and on internal environments, but when it gets deployed to an Azure app it behaves as if the request was indeed local.

According to the documentation this actually checks if the originating IP was `127.0.0.1` but I don't understand how can that be. Is this just some weird Azure underlying problem?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see same problem. But, I think, you can try doing IsLocal with the following code.

```
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLocal(this HttpRequest req)
    {
        var connection = req.HttpContext.Connection;
        if (connection.RemoteIpAddress != null)
        {
            if (connection.LocalIpAddress != null)
            {
                return connection.RemoteIpAddress.Equals(connection.LocalIpAddress);
            } 

            return IPAddress.IsLoopback(connection.RemoteIpAddress);
        }

        if (connection.RemoteIpAddress == null && connection.LocalIpAddress == null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```